# Python Array with string AND integer indices

Tags: python, arrays, string

I'm trying to create an array that uses strings and integers as indices.

```
aDemo[int]["string"] = "Test"
```

Is it possible and if yes how is it declared?

Comment: Do you mean two-dimensional array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A data structure which can be indexed by keys (like strings, or most everything else) is called an [associative array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array). The built-in python implementation of this is called [`dict` (dictionary)](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). You can create a `dict` using curly braces syntax:

```
aDemo = []
a = { "apple": "red", "banana": "yellow", "cucumber": "green" }
aDemo.append(a)
print aDemo[0]["apple"] # "red"
```

A `dict` has plenty of other methods and ways to be modified and created, just check the official documentation.

Comment: I found out its important to use aDemo.append(a.copy()). Otherwise each aDemo[x]["apple"] will have the same value.

Comment: I don't understand what index `x` is supposed to be. If you append `a` directly, you will actually just store a reference to `a` in `aDemo`, so any change to `a` will also affect `aDemo[0]`. If you do not want that, you indeed need to append a copy of `a`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just declare an array like:

```
fruits["apple","orange","banana"]
```

And access its contents like:

```
fruits[0] -> apple
fruits[1] -> orange
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

use [list](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) inside [dict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html)

```
l=[0,1,1,{"agf":"hi"}]
>>> l
[0, 1, 1, {'agf': 'hi'}]
>>> l[3]['agf']
'hi'
```

Comment: You meant using a dict in a list not the other way round.